# Set paste on git commit

Tags: vim, git

When performing git commit, VIM opens to edit the commit message. I would like VIM to already be in `paste` mode when this happens. What environment checks might I be able to perform in Autocommands to set the option? Of course, I don't want VIM to be in paste mode when opening any arbitrary file, otherwise I would just add `set paste` to `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste` is a global option so we must be careful:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead COMMIT_EDITMSG set paste
autocmd BufLeave COMMIT_EDITMSG set nopaste
```

Should help.

Comment: Perfect, romainl, thank you once again! Tell me, how might I have found `COMMIT_EDITMSG` for myself?

Comment: It's easy: each time you use Vim to write your commit message, you actually use a temporary file located under a different randomized path and that file is *always* named `COMMIT_EDITMSG` which makes it a perfect hook for an `autocmd`. Note that my first reflex would be to do what Ingo suggested but `paste` can't be set locally, even with `:setlocal`, so the `FileType` option is not that great here.

Answer (score 3):

The used *filetype* is `gitcommit`, therefore you can set this via an autocmd:

```
:autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal paste
```

or (with `:filetype plugin on`), you could put the `:setlocal` command into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`.